# The site randomly logs me out

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

Is it normal that SO logs me out randomly from time to time, most often just after starting a new browser? Usually I open 2-3 different tabs from SO, and the some of them log in OK, but the rest greet me as a new user.

EDIT:

This happens both on Firefox and Chrome, both running on Windows XP and Linux. Usually it happens when I open 2 tabs at the same time (some concurrency bug perhaps?)

Comment: This would most likely be a localized issue on your machine with your browser settings or behavior.  Some more info is needed about your machine.  Which browser are you using? OS?

Comment: @Troggy, updated question. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: This seems to happen to me as well.

Comment: How long has this been happening?  Is it a recent phenomenon (last day or two)?

Comment: @Kevin, I would say a month or so. Happened 3 times so far I think.

Comment: I have not had this issue in the last week, but i had it a couple of times in the past. Usually after opening news tabs by middle clicking on interesting questions in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't duplicate this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this bug either. Happens usually when I have very little time to check on the new questions :(